# Google web font displaying strangely at certain pixel sizes on Chrome/Mac

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts, google-webfonts

I'm using the Google Web font "Buenard" and having a difficult time getting it to display on Chrome. I know there are issues with font rendering and hinting across the various browers, but this is something else altogether. Instead of the intended font, Chrome is displaying some other dingbat font on my system. It looks great in Safari.

I can't share a link, because the site in question is behind a protected login. However, check out this screenshot to see what I'm looking at:
http://bit.ly/ImiiDM

In the CSS, I am using a font stack of '"Buenard", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;' I tried also just using '"Buenard", serif;' No effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: Start by renaming the font file(s), renaming the filenames to match in your CSS, and swapping the font-family value for something indisputably unique (like domain.tld-font1.foo), then hard refresh.  If that's no help you may have to trivially alter the font (occasionally http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator/ helps in this regard, occasionally it exacerbates).

Comment: show us the code that is loading the font

Comment: @reisio: The font is loading directly from the Google fonts API, using their prescribed link code, as follows:  

    `<link href=​"http:​/​/​fonts.googleapis.com/​css?family=Buenard:​ 400,700" rel=​"stylesheet" type=​"text/​css">`
  
I'll try to load the font locally and see if that makes any difference. I'll also try the fontsquirrel generator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using stylesheets to attach the font just search the web for your desired font and download it and attach it like so:

```
@font-face {
font-family: buenard;
src: url('buenard.ttf');
}
```

After that you can use it just like a normal CSS declaration:

```
p.custom_font{
font-family: buenard; /* no .ttf */
}
```